# CSS Font usage at website

Tags: css, fonts

I would like to ask can if I use font legally at our own websites that one of Google website uses at here http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html ? Because the code and files are open for usage, so I would like to know about possible consequences of using it.

Comment: This is wrong place to get proper answer to legal question. If you can't find clear license to use and worried about legal issues consult real lawer or pick fonts (or whatever you need) with license you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it. It's an open source font even if it was designed by Google Android.

You can get the package [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto). Click on '@font-face Kit'

Comment: Thank you ComputerArts for your information!

Comment: You're welcome. The license can be found here: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: +1 for knowing the font and proper location to get one/read license. Usual legal note: @KenTang, it is up to you to decide if Apache 2.0 license is ok for your site.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am here to serve! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Other way google webfont or cufon for more information click links below

```
  http://www.google.com/webfonts
```

or:

```
 http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/
```